# Pressing qpushbutton when qprocessevent waitforfinished

Tags: qt, qprocess, qpushbutton

I need to run an external application by pressing a button and freeze the main application.

Using the below code when the main application is freezed the button on it seems to enqueue the event (or the main application).

When the main application returns available the button run the relative event the number of times that was clicked when it was disabled.

I hope you undestand.

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
ui.ProgramPushButton->blockSignals(true);
ui.ProgramPushButton->setEnabled(false);
QApplication::processEvents();

process.setWorkingDirectory(external_program_workingdir);

process.start(file);

process.waitForFinished(-1);

ui.ProgramPushButton->blockSignals(false);
ui.ProgramPushButton->setEnabled(true);
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

what i miss?

Answer (score 0):

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
ui.ProgramPushButton->blockSignals(true);
ui.serviceProgramPushButton->setEnabled(false);
```

It looks like the blockSignals function should be applied to **ui.serviceProgramPushButton**, not **ui.ProgramPushButton**

Comment: Ok, have you tried running QApplication::processEvents() when the process exits, before you unblock the signals and renable the button?